# Is there anyway to confirm configuration settings are set

Tags: iphone

On iPhone once IT admin push the configuration file ( mobileconfig ), is there anyway a iphone client can confirm if this configue file is installed on phone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the iPhone go to Settings -> General -> Profiles, it will list all the configuration profiles (.mobileconfig) and provisioning profiles (.mobileprovision) on the phone.

Comment: I'm sorry if i am not clear in the question, i mean, is it possible programmatically?